# jqGrid - ambiguous npage parameter from prmNames property

Tags: jqgrid

I'm using jqGrid to load data with virtual scrolling. It is working ok, but I'm also trying to make it load some data ahead, at least one page ahead, to avoid the loading appearing while the user is scrolling. In documentation, the npage parameter is the one specified to handle this. I assigned boolean values to it, int values from 1 to 100, but  doesn't have any effect. What am I missing?

> If you set the npage option in prmNames, then the grid will sometimes
>   request more than one page at a time; if not, it will just perform
>   multiple GET requests.

[jqGrid Docs](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions)
[demo virtual scrolling-npage is set to null](http://www.trirand.com/blog/phpjqgrid/examples/paging/scrollbar/default.php)

Answer (score 0):

You have misunderstood the documentation a little bit. You need to set the `npage` property of `prmNames` object to a string, for example like this:

```
prmNames: {
    npage: 'npage'
}
```

This will tell jqGrid that when dynamic scrolling is enabled (the value of `scroll` option is different than `False`) it can (at own will so not always) request more than one page by adding the number of pages it want to the request under the key by name which you have specified in `npage` property.

Comment: @klaudyuxxx Not working how? Are you sure you have generated situation in which jqGrid would decide to request more than one page (in order to do that for example scroll very fast to the bottom so it would need to get more than one page) if you are scrolling by one page it will almost never request for a page "in advance". Also are you sure you are inspecting you request properly for the new parameter comming in?